# Sometime unable to get access token in iphone os 10.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

In iPhone 7 and 6 sometime unable to access device token of iPhone iOS 10.2.

**Code:**

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 10.0){
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
        if( !error ){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
    }];
}
```

**Enabled:**

1. project > target > capabilities > push notification
2. project > target > capabilities > background modes > Remote notification

Comment: what `error` do you get back?

Comment: didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken and even didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError methods are not getting called

Comment: do you get an error from your call to `requestAuthorizationWithOptions:` ?  Do you know how to check?  You're already checking to see if error is nil.

Comment: I don't know how to check from requestAuthorizationWithOptions ?

Comment: requestAuthorizationWithOptions checked not getting any error

Comment: Are you checking push notification by running in device or simulator

Comment: Have you got any solution ? Bacause i am facing same problem.

Comment: Running in device

Comment: Still facing same issue.